# Laravel 6.9.0 validation.php translated messages not showing if they do not start with a variable / property

Tags: laravel, validation, error-handling

So I translated by hand the error messages in the validation.php file for the /en/ locale since the site is almost finished and I figured since it needs only one language (not English) it's not worth refactoring everything to a new locale, instead, just translate the EN one.

But, I am currently facing the issue where a translated message, which starts with :attribute or any other :variable will get displayed properly, but if it starts with Cyrillic it does not. Here is an example from the validation.php -

```
'accepted' => 'Трябва да приемете :attribute.', // DOES NOT WORK
'confirmed' => ':attribute не съвпада със стойността за потвърждение.', // WORKS
```

If a message isn't working, all I have to do is put the :attribute or whatever it might be called called, at the beginning of the string and it works now...

This is really weird and I am not sure if it has anything to do with the fact that this is under the /en/ lang folder or something else. I tried to find a solution for a couple of hours now but I cant find anything related to my case so I am hoping for some help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after days of digging around, it turns out that when a form submits a huge textarea content, such as like 2 paragraphs of text, the form input is sent to a cookie in order to flash the errors when the validation fails. But since the textarea contains a lot of text, the validation fails, but the error flash also fails, silently,and $errors is left empty.

https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-not-showing-validation-errors-when-textarea-is-filled-with-lots-of-text?

A possible solution is to use FILE for the session driver in session.php, as mentioned in the issue linked above.