# Laravel does not show errors when there are many errors. It,s Bug?

Tags: php, laravel

Duplicate of https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31123

- Laravel Version: 6.8.0 ,6.10.1
- PHP Version: 7.4
- Languages from https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang

#### Description:

For some languages, when validated errors  too much, errors not show in blade (not send in session)

Language example: ru (not show >=6 errors), si (not show >=8 errors) in my code.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

New laravel 6 app + https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang

conf/app.php

```
locale' => 'ru',
// locale' => 'si',
```

View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
    <form class="form" method="post" action="{{route('testvalid')}}">
        @csrf
        <input class="form-control" name="field1" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field2" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field3" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field4" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field5" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field6" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field7" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field8" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field9" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field10" />
        <input class="form-control" name="field11" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Action:

```
 public function testvalidpost(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'field1'=>['required'],
            'field2'=>['required'],
            'field3'=>['required'],
            'field4'=>['required'],
            'field5'=>['required'],
            'field6'=>['required'],
            'field7'=>['required'],
            'field8'=>['required'],
            'field9'=>['required'],
            'field10'=>['required'],
            'field11'=>['required'],
        ]);
        echo ok;
    }
```

Comment: I believe your validation should be `validate(['field1' => 'required']);` not `validate(['field1' => ['required']]);`

Comment: @RobBiermann validate worked. Session not work, when many error. And its bug on same languages. En lang - work, si lang - not work.

Comment: @RobBiermann laravel validation support array in rules. Its not code error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `SESSION_DRIVER=file` to get it work

[See related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614407/laravel-6-9-0-validation-php-translated-messages-not-showing-if-they-do-not-star)

Comment: Not work :( Your set 'si'  or 'ru' language with translate files?