# Laravel old POST data empty after validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, nginx

I am printing the contents of `old()` in my view:

```
{{ print_r(old('steps'), true) }}
```

When I submit the form with the following validation rules, the `old` data prints fine:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'steps.*.name' => 'required',
]);
```

When I add more rules, the `old` data dissapears completely:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'steps.*.name' => 'required',
    'steps.*.title' => 'required',
    'steps.*.type' => 'required',
    'steps.*.answer_options' => 'nullable|required_if:steps.*.type,Question',
    'steps.*.input_type' => 'nullable|required_if:steps.*.type,Input',
]);
```

I've confirmed this only happens AFTER validation. How do I fix this?

Comment: make sure that your SESSION_DRIVER in `.env` file is something else then `cookie` for example try with `file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try to set `SESSION_DRIVER=file` to get it work

[See related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59735131/laravel-does-not-show-errors-when-there-are-many-errors-it-s-bug/59736250)

Comment: That worked, can you explain why? would increasing COOKIE size in the server config also work?

Comment: According to Denislav Karagiozov response here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614407/laravel-6-9-0-validation-php-translated-messages-not-showing-if-they-do-not-star): "when a form submits a huge portion of content, such as like 2 paragraphs of text, the form input is sent to a cookie in order to flash the errors when the validation fails. But since the input contains a lot of text, the validation fails, but the error flash also fails, silently,and $errors is left empty."