# Problem inserting MySQL row through Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I wasn't quite sure how to format the name because I've done a bit of troubleshooting and still can't even narrow down quite what the issue is at the moment as to why the code I have isn't inserting a row into my SQL database. The code right now, which is located inside the EventController file, is as follows

```
    public function create(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => ['required', 'unique:events', 'string', 'max:50'],
            'event_desc_short' => ['required', 'string', 'max:120'],
            'event_desc' => ['required', 'string'],
            'event_free' => ['required', 'boolean'],
            'event_low_cost' => ['nullable', 'numeric', 'between:0,9999.99', 'required_if:event_free,false'],
            'event_high_cost' => ['nullable', 'numeric', 'between:0,999999.99', 'required_if:event_free,false'],
            'event_featured' => ['required', 'boolean'],
            'event_feature_type' => ['nullable', 'string', 'required_if:event_featured,true', Rule::in(['yearly', 'monthly', 'weekly'])],
            'event_daily_budget' => ['nullable', 'required_if:event_featured,true', 'numeric', 'between:0,999999.99'],
            'event_picture_link' => ['nullable'],
            'location' => ['nullable'],
            ]);

        $event = new Event;
        $event->name = $request->input('name');
        $event->event_desc_short = $request->input('event_desc_short');
        $event->event_desc = $request->input('event_desc');
        $event->event_free = $request->input('event_free');
        $event->event_posting_business = Auth::id();
        $event->event_low_cost = $request->input('event_low_cost');
        $event->event_high_cost = $request->input('event_high_cost');
        $event->event_featured = $request->input('event_featured');
        $event->event_feature_type = $request->input('event_feature_type');
        $event->event_daily_budget = $request->input('event_daily_budget');
        $event->location = $request->input('location');
        $event->save();

        return redirect('/userlanding')->with('success', 'Created Event Successfully!');
        }
```

And the Event model is as follows..

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';

    protected $fillable = [

        "name", "event_desc_short" , "event_desc" , "event_free" , "event_low_cost" ,
        "event_high_cost" , "event_featured" , "event_feature_type" , "event_daily_budget", "event_picture_link", "location"
    ];
}
```

And the form is as follows

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'EventController@create', 'method', 'POST']) !!}
                            <div class="form-group text-left">
                                {{Form::label('name', 'Event Name', ['class' => 'text-left'])}}
                                {{Form::text('name', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-left">
                                {{Form::label('event_desc_short', 'Event Description (Short)', ['class' => 'text-left'])}}
                                {{Form::text('event_desc_short', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                                <small class="form-text text-muted">A short description to catch viewer's attention</small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-left">
                                {{Form::label('event_desc', 'Event Description (Full)', ['class' => 'text-left'])}}
                                {{Form::text('event_desc', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                                <small class="form-text text-muted">Full description to be viewed on viewing</small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-left">
                                {{Form::label('event_free', 'Is this event free to attend?', ['class' => 'text-left'])}}
                                {{Form::select('event_free', ['true' => 'Yes', 'false' => 'No'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'onchange' => 'openCostPanel()'])}}
                            </div>
                            <div id="not-free-event-options">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="form-group text-left">
                                            {{Form::label('event_low_cost', 'Minimum Cost to attend Event')}}
                                            {{Form::number('event_low_cost', 'value', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="form-group text-left">
                                            {{Form::label('event_high_cost', 'Maximum Cost to attend Event')}}
                                            {{Form::number('event_high_cost', 'value', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-left">
                                {{Form::label('event_featured', 'Would you like to feature this event?')}}
                                {{Form::select('event_featured', ['false' => 'No', 'true' => 'Yes'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'onchange' => 'openFeaturedPanel()'])}}
                            </div>
                            <div id="featured-event-options">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="form-group text-left">
                                            {{Form::label('event_feature_type', 'What type of featuring would you like?')}}
                                            {{Form::select('event_feature_type', ['yearly' => 'Yearly', 'monthly' => 'Monthly', 'weekly' => 'Weekly'], ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="form-group text-left">
                                            {{Form::label('event_daily_budget', 'How much would you like to spend to be featured?')}}
                                            {{Form::number('event_daily_budget', 'value', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                                            <small class="form-text text-muted">Bid amount.</small>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-left">
                                {{Form::label('event_location', 'Event Address', ['class' => 'text-left'])}}
                                {{Form::text('event_location', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                            </div>
                            {{Form::submit('Create Event', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

After looking carefully at my code for a long time, and searching through Stack Overflow, I seem to be missing something probably super minuet that is preventing it from submitting.

Weirder still, in an attempt to debug the error, I added a error message template which is supposed to display an error, which looks as follows

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{$error}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif

@if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{session('success')}}
    </div>
@endif

@if(session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{session('error')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

This is included on the template with the form on it, and when submitting the form it redirects successfully to the page /userlanding but there is no message on it, of any type (error or success)

I'm super confused, as there doesn't seem to be any issues with the code as it is.

Comment: could you share error message you get

Comment: In what? As I said nothing shows up from the error message file, I tried searching for error logs in the laravel folders but every logging file hasn't been updated for a couple days so nothing was reported to them.

Comment: Unrelated but try using $event = Event::create($request->all()); $event->event_posting_business = Auth::id(); $event->save();

Comment: @JacobHyde Still didn't work. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `SESSION_DRIVER=file` to get it work

[Seems related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59735131/laravel-does-not-show-errors-when-there-are-many-errors-it-s-bug/59736250)

don't forget to clear config cache

```
php artisan config:clear
```

**Edit**

The validation rules

`'event_free' => ['required', 'boolean']` // `boolean` means  accepts 0 OR 1 (`'true'` OR `'false'` values are considered as strings)

Same for `'event_featured' => ['required', 'boolean']`

So you must update :

```
{{Form::select('event_free', ['1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'onchange' => 'openCostPanel()'])}}

{{Form::select('event_featured', ['0' => 'No', '1' => 'Yes'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'onchange' => 'openFeaturedPanel()'])}}
```

Comment: The file input is a placeholder at the moment to insert into the database, I haven't setup all of the folders to allow for image uploads yet so I just have it being inserted as null, so the file configuration isn't the issue. I'll clear the config cache and see if anything appears.

Comment: Your problem is probably with validation function. According to Denislav Karagiozov response here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614407/laravel-6-9-0-validation-php-translated-messages-not-showing-if-they-do-not-star): "when a form submits a huge portion of content, such as like 2 paragraphs of text, the form input is sent to a cookie in order to flash the errors when the validation fails. But since the input contains a lot of text, the validation fails, but the error flash also fails, silently,and $errors is left empty."

Comment: SESSION_DRIVER=file and  Setup folders for image uploads are different things

Comment: I did as such, but there still isn't anything returning as an error

Comment: Your app is running on top of Laravel 6 ?

Comment: Correct, it is laravel 6.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206211/discussion-between-foued-moussi-and-baddeveloper22).

Comment: Want to add the final answer to be public since we found it in chat, but I had nested the form inside of an additional form tag which was messing up the submission of the form. Removing that allowed the form to be submitted successfully. Wanted to go on record and say many thanks to @Foued MOUSSI for providing outstanding help throughout the process.