# How to solve Laravel 419 csrf token error

Tags: php, laravel

I know that mostly the `419 error` has to do with `csrf` token in `Laravel` and I have correctly added `meta` tag and attach it with every `ajax` request. The page I am having problem with is not `ajax` submission.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

For any other forms I am using [spatie/laravel-html](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-html) repo so it adds `_token` on all the forms.

Following is the `html` of one of the form

```
<form method="POST" action="https://example.com/login" class="needs-validation">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="NmvrH2BZtzCg4ity9cRDG9JXgJER3EUtO0BnXxGH">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="form-control-label required">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="form-control-label required">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div>
        <span data-href="https://example.com/register" class="clickable-row btn float-left">Sign Up</span>
        <button type="submit" class="btn float-right">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my project only one route `/account` is causing `419 error`. Strange thing is that it throws error when clicked on `update` first time and then if I go back to the same page it works.

I have tried clearing `cache`, changing route name or change the folder permission of `storage` on production but nothing seems to solve the issue.

What else can I do to resolve the error?

Thank you

Comment: You need to add the token for the forms that gets submitted as well.

Comment: I have done that or else it would not work on second submit

Comment: try this 
php artisan key:generate

Comment: Could you plz add your full blade code ?

Comment: try adding @csrf blade gate instead  of the tag and check

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `SESSION_DRIVER=file` in your `.env` file

Then run

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

And retry

Comment: What does the session driver has to do with anything here?

Comment: I am using `database` as session driver, but I have tried clearing `cache` and `config` with no luck. Doesnt submit first time but submits next time

Comment: According to Denislav Karagiozov response here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614407/laravel-6-9-0-validation-php-translated-messages-not-showing-if-they-do-not-star): "when a form submits a huge portion of content, such as like 2 paragraphs of text, the form input is sent to a cookie in order to flash the errors when the validation fails. But since the input contains a lot of text, the validation fails, but the error flash also fails, maybe csrf token chek fails also silently, and $errors is left empty." seems related.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf, creating a meta tag with the csrf token can be used for ajax requests. You still need to add a csrf token field to forms you are submitting. Try adding `@csrf` in your form. It will create a hidden field with the token.

```
<form method="POST" action="/target">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: I use [spatie/laravel-html](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-html) so `_token` is added automatically.

Comment: @MikeRoss Can you post the generated HTML of the form?

Comment: I have added one of the generate form in the question